# Reboot after power failure for MacPro 3,1 early 2008 using Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, windows, mac

I'm using a Mac Pro 3,1 early 2008, with Windows 7 64 bit installed to run as a Server.

Is it possible to make it automatically restart after a power recovery?

Previously I was using a Pentium 4 Dell Dimension 3100, where there is an option in the BIOS to set `turn on pc after power failure`. But for this Mac, or any Apple product, I can't find it anywhere.

I found the solution for Ubuntu from this question: [Reboot after power failure for Mac mini running Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/212434/reboot-after-power-failure-for-mac-mini-running-ubuntu), so I think there could be a solution for Windows.

Comment: If you have the software to your UPS installed there might be an option.  I would verify that and report what you found.

Comment: Thanks Louis for your reply. Anyway, i don't use any UPS. my power cable for Mac plug in directly to source. If possible, i don't want to use UPS. :-). I want my Mac act as what my P4 can do previously. Previously for my P4, i run script to auto shutdown in between 4am & auto start at 6am & the rest for my software will auto start after that. For my Mac, the problem is, it cannot auto start after shutdown or power failure. i need to turn it on manually. Any solution?

Comment: Sorry, not Louis, its Ramhound. :-)

Comment: If the hardware doesn't support this feature it wouldn't be possible.

Comment: Thanks Ramhound. I will try to use relay as a switch for 'ON' button. once done, i post it here the result. :-)