# Automatically turn on Mac OSX whenever shut down

Tags: macos, mac, macos-sierra

I've already scheduled my OSX desktop to auto turn on everyday at 0AM, but I use it as a server and I want to make sure it'll auto turn on whenever it shuts down, be it a power failure, a crash or whatever.

Does anyone know a way?

Comment: Does the question [reboot after power failure for Mac mini running Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/q/212434/272824) have your answer in 'you can check "Start up automatically after a power failure" in the "Energy Saver" System Preferences'?

Comment: You'd think if you'd already got as far as the schedule, you'd have spotted the power failure pref on the way there... but it can't restart if it's kernel panicked, that's a manual press the button scenario, afaik

Comment: @Tetsujin I would hope so, but it wasn't mentioned in the question. And they could have turned it into one of those hidden buttons that you have to discover by hovering over it.

Answer (score 1):

In Lion there was the option to restart on freeze, in the Energy Saving panel.
Now you have to resort to the command line:
`sudo systemsetup -setrestartfreeze on -setrestartpowerfailure on`

Not all Mac models support all the functions.
for example my macbook can restart on freeze but cannot restart on power failure; you can check status and availability of the function with the same command:
`sudo systemsetup -getrestartfreeze -getrestartpowerfailure`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but you might be able to set multiple startup events per day using 'pmset'.  http://osxdaily.com/2009/11/28/schedule-your-mac-to-startup-via-the-command-line/ .  For instance, you could tell it to start up every hour and then at worst it will get turned off at 1 minute after the hour, and start up at the next.  I assume power-on events while it's running have no effect; research that before enacting it.

However, that's not guaranteed to always have your "server" up.  If it were a Linux or Windows box, you could virtualize it and put it in a datacenter with actual uptime guarantees.  Uptime guarantees require multiple people maintaining vigilance.